# Javascript window.alert change to text

Tags: javascript, html

I have an simple question,

How to change

```
window.alert ('Please input data into the \"Part No.\" field.');
```

to be just text, no alert

```
Please input data into the \"Part No.\" field.
```

Comment: I have no clue what you mean.

Comment: What do you mean to be just text, where do you want it to appear?
Do you mean convert it to a variable?

Comment: maybe window.html () ?

Comment: insert it on the page?

Comment: You don't need \ for ". When you use `singlequote` to quote the string, `doublequote` can be used as a part of the string. You can also do vice versa. What you can't do is use same quote to quote the string and use that as a part of the string too.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to simply write it to your document?  Include this in a `<script>` block in your `<body>`

```
document.write('<p>Please input data into the &quot;Part No.&quot; field.</p>');
```

EDIT: On rethinking this, I now believe that you want the message to appear after the input element.  Here, assuming your input element is `<input id="part_no_field" />`

```
// Create a message node
var messageNode = document.createElement('p');
messageNode.innerText = 'Please input data into the &quot;Part No.&quot; field.';

// Find your "part number" field
var partField = document.getElementById('part_no_field');

// Append the message node after your "part number" field
if (partField.nextSibling) {
    partField.parentNode.insertBefore(messageNode, partField.nextSibling);
} else {
    partField.parentNode.appendChild(messageNode);
}
```

Comment: Once you call that, there won't be a "Part No." field.

Comment: No need to escape double-quotes inside single-quotes.  Should use &quot; though

Comment: He means `document.write` rewrites the whole page, therefore `Part No.` won't exist

Comment: In-body scripts, e.g. `<body> <script>document.write('')</script></body>` will not rewrite the whole page.

Comment: Edited to append a node after the input field.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you want the text to be placed:

```
var text = 'Please input data into the \'Part No.\' field.'

//inside a div
div.innerHTML = text;

//the bottom of the body
document.body.innerHTML+=text;

//an input field
input.value = text;

//rewriting the document
document.open();
document.write(text);
document.close();
```